# Force layout drag behaviour with transition on zoom but no transition on drag

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I think the question is very easy. I have this site for you for demontrating what I mean: **http://arda-maps.org/familytree/** So if you add some persons there to the screen you are able to **drag** and **zoom** the view.

The zooming is totally fine. The duration for zooming is great. But I don't like the duration when dragging and would like to disable it just there. Basically this is the code:

```
g.transition().duration(450).attr("transform", "translate(" + zoombuttonTranslate + ")scale(" + zoombuttonScale + ")");
```

So the question is how to disable the transition/duration just on the dragging event? Is this even possible somehow?

Comment: you can interrupt the transition by starting another, zero-length transition on the same object, in the same name-space.  In your case: `g.transition().duration(0)`.  If you want to better manage transition collisions then you should be using named transitions like `g.transition("gTransition").duration(450)`, in which case you can interrupt it with `g.transition("gTransition").duration(0)`

Comment: Sounds good, but how should that be possible? I have no idea how to split up the scale from the translate. I need both separated. But I don't think that is possible. Your solution sounds like that you do not split them up. Yeah that is easy in that case. Or did I get you wrong my friend? If not please tell me what to write in the **transform** statement.

Comment: Ok, I thought you were talking about the transition on the node label when you drag the node. Do I misunderstand? Ahh, are you talking about setzoom?

Comment: OK, the recommended way to handle this is to use [drag + zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708) "using stopPropagation to allow the drag behavior to take precedence over panning."

Comment: Thank you. But your example does not have any duration value, right? Yes as I said, want a duration on the zooming, but none on the dragging. =)

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/cool-Blue/42514ca0daad76ecfde9) is my solution using the techniques in my answer. I tested it against your page as a way to test out how it deploys and it works fine.

Comment: It worked _almost_ fine in fact, [here](https://gist.github.com/cool-Blue/42514ca0daad76ecfde9/d4b679c1fe01d4b32b60187429ba2e93d9f57656) is a final version tested and working against your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Phase I

I think this is close...
It just needs to be verified that it will play nice with the drag behaviour on the nodes.

### Stategy

- use `d3.event.sourceEvent.type` to check for mousemove
- augment the current transform state using `d3.transform`
- transition *translate* and *scale* for mouse wheel events and no transition for mouse button events

### Working example

```js
var width = 600, height = 200-16,
    margin = {top: 25, right: 5, bottom: 5, left: 5},
    w = width - margin.left - margin.right,
    h = height - margin.top - margin.bottom,

    zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.4, 4])
      .on("zoom", zoomed),
    svg = d3.select("#viz").attr({width: width, height: height})
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(zoom),
    transText = svg.append("text")
      .text("transform = translate ( margin.left , margin.top )")
      .style("fill", "#5c5c5c")
      .attr("dy", "-.35em")
    surface = svg.append("rect")
      .attr({width: w, height: h})
      .style({"pointer-events": "all", fill: "#ccc", "stroke-width": 3, "stroke": "#fff"}),
    surfaceText = svg.append("text")
      .text("pointer-events: all")
      .style("fill", "#5c5c5c")
      .attr({"dy": "1em", "dx": ".2em"})
    content = svg.append("g").attr("id", "content")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)"),
    contentText = content.append("text")
    .text("transform = translate ( d3.event.translate ) scale ( d3.event.scale )")
    .style("fill", "#5c5c5c")
    .attr({"dy": 50, "dx": 20})
    content.selectAll("rect")
      .data([[20,60],[140,60]])
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr({height: 50, width: 50})
      .style({"stroke-width": 3, "stroke": "#ccc"})
      .each(function(d){
        d3.select(this).attr({x: d[0], y: d[1]});
      });

  function zoomStart(){

  }
  function zoomed(){
    return d3.event.sourceEvent.buttons ? zoomDrag.call(this) : zoomScale.call(this)
  }
  function zoomDrag(){
  var t = d3.transform(content.attr("transform"));
    t.translate = d3.event.translate;
    content.attr("transform", t.toString());
  }
  function zoomScale(){
    var t = d3.transform(content.attr("transform"));
    t.translate = d3.event.translate; t.scale = d3.event.scale;
    content.transition().duration(450).attr("transform", t.toString());
  }
```

```css
svg {
      outline: 1px solid #282f51;
      pointer-events: all;
    }
    g {
      outline: 1px solid red;
      shape-rednering: "geometricPrecision";
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="viz"></svg>
```

---

## Phase II

### *Incorporate an FDG*

Since the FDG must be inside the canvas container, it's necessary to stop node level events from propagating to the canvas.  This was done in the OP code by using a custom drag behaviour, stopping propagation on *dragstart* and adding back some of the `force.drag` behaviour (plus setting `d.fixed` = true`).  This is great if you don't mind losing some of the`force.drag`features like sticking nodes on mouseover.  This is nice for capturing small, energetic nodes though.  So, in order to get the best of both worlds, you can hook the`force.drag` behaviour.

### Strategy

- apply the same principles as in Phase I but do a cross-browser test for mouse wheel events.
- add standard `force.drag` to the nodes
- hook the `force.drag` to add custom behaviour
- only fix nodes on <kbd>shift</kbd>-drag *(or <kbd>shift</kbd>-dragend)*
- *for touch devices, also fix nodes if touches > 1 at dragstart*

The last two points allow fixed nodes to be easily released if desired.

### force.drag hook

```
        //hook force.drag behaviour
        var stdDragStart = force.drag().on("dragstart.force");
        force.drag()
            .on("dragstart", function(d){
                //prevent dragging on the nodes from dragging the canvas
                d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                stdDragStart.call(this, d);
            });
```

### Working example

```js
//debug panel/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var alpha = d3.select("#alpha").text("waiting..."),
  cog = d3.select("#wrapAlpha").insert("i", "#fdg").classed("fa fa-cog fa-spin", true).datum({instID: null}),
  fdgInst = d3.select("#fdg");
elapsedTime = ElapsedTime("#panel", {margin: 0, padding: 0})
 .message(function (id) {
  return 'fps : ' + d3.format(" >8.3f")(1/this.aveLap())
 });
elapsedTime.consoleOn = true;

alpha.log = function(e, instID) {
 elapsedTime.mark().timestamp();
 alpha.text(d3.format(" >8.4f")(e.alpha));
 fdgInst.text("fdg instance: " + instID);
};

d3.select("#update").on("click", (function() {
 var dataSet = false;
 return function() {
  //fdg.force.stop();
  fdg(dataSets[(dataSet = !dataSet, +dataSet)])
 }
})());
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var dataSets = [{
    "nodes"    : [
     {"name": "node1", "r": 10},
     {"name": "node2", "r": 10},
     {"name": "node3", "r": 30},
     {"name": "node4", "r": 15}
    ],
    "edges": [
     {"source": 2, "target": 0},
     {"source": 2, "target": 1},
     {"source": 2, "target": 3}
    ]
   },
   {
    "nodes":[
     {"name": "node1", "r": 20},
     {"name": "node2", "r": 10},
     {"name": "node3", "r": 30},
     {"name": "node4", "r": 15},
     {"name": "node5", "r": 10},
     {"name": "node6", "r": 10}
    ],
    "edges":[
     {"source": 2, "target": 0},
     {"source": 2, "target": 1},
     {"source": 2, "target": 3},
     {"source": 2, "target": 4},
     {"source": 2, "target": 5}
    ]
   }
  ],
  svg = SVG({width: 600, height: 200-34, margin: {top: 25, right: 5, bottom: 5, left: 5}}, "#viz"),
  fdg = FDG(svg, alpha.log);

fdg(dataSets[0]);

function SVG (size, selector){
 //delivers an svg background with zoom/drag context in the selector element
 //if height or width is NaN, assume it is a valid length but ignore margin
 var margin = size.margin || {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
   unitW = isNaN(size.width), unitH = isNaN(size.height),
   w = unitW ? size.width : size.width - margin.left - margin.right,
   h = unitH ? size.height : size.height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
   zoomed = function(){return this},

   zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.4, 4])
    .on("zoom", function(d, i, j){
     zoomed.call(this, d, i, j);
    }),

   svg = d3.select(selector).selectAll("svg").data([["transform root"]]);
   svg.enter().append("svg");
   svg.attr({width: size.width, height: size.height});

 var g = svg.selectAll("#zoom").data(id),
   gEnter = g.enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom)
    .attr({class: "outline", id: "zoom"}),
   zoomText = gEnter.append("text")
    .text("transform = translate ( margin.left , margin.top )")
    .style("fill", "#5c5c5c")
    .attr("dy", "-.35em"),
   surface = gEnter.append("rect")
    .attr({width: w, height: h})
    .style({"pointer-events": "all", fill: "#ccc", "stroke-width": 3, "stroke": "#fff"}),
   surfaceText = gEnter.append("text")
    .text("pointer-events: none")
    .style("fill", "#5c5c5c")
    .attr({"dy": "1em", "dx": ".2em"});

 g.h = h;
 g.w = w;
 g.onZoom = function(cb){zoomed = cb;};

 return g;
}
function FDG (svg, tickLog) {
 var instID = Date.now();
 force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([svg.w, svg.h])
  .charge(-1000)
  .linkDistance(50)
  .on("end", function(){
   // manage dead instances of force
   // only stop if this instance is the current owner
   if(cog.datum().instID != instID) return true;
   cog.classed("fa-spin", false);
   elapsedTime.stop();
  })
  .on("start", function(){
   // mark as active and brand the insID to establish ownership
   cog.classed("fa-spin", true).datum().instID = instID;
   elapsedTime.start();
  });

 function fdg(data) {
    force
     .nodes(data.nodes)
     .links(data.edges)
     .on("tick", (function(instID) {
      return function(e) {
       if(tickLog) tickLog.call(this, e, instID);
       lines.attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
       }).attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
       }).attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
       }).attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
       });
       node.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")"
       });
      }
     })(instID))
     .start();

  svg.onZoom(zoomed);

  hookDrag(force.drag(), "dragstart.force", function(d) {
   // prevent dragging on the nodes from dragging the canvas
   var e = d3.event.sourceEvent;
   e.stopPropagation();
   d.fixed = e.shiftKey || e.touches && (e.touches.length > 1);
  });
  hookDrag(force.drag(), "dragend.force", function(d) {
   // prevent dragging on the nodes from dragging the canvas
   var e = d3.event.sourceEvent;
   d.fixed = e.shiftKey || d.fixed;
  });

  var content = svg.selectAll("g#fdg").data([data]);
  content.enter().append("g").attr({"id": "fdg", class: "outline"});

  var contentText = content.selectAll(".contentText")
   .data(["transform = translate ( d3.event.translate ) scale ( d3.event.scale )"])
   .enter().append("text").classed("contentText", true)
   .text(id)
   .style("fill", "#5c5c5c")
   .attr({"dy": 20, "dx": 20});

  var lines = content.selectAll(".links")
     .data(linksData),
    linesEnter = lines.enter()
     .insert("line", d3.select("#nodes") ? "#nodes" : null)
     .attr("class", "links")
     .attr({stroke: "steelblue", "stroke-width": 3});
  var nodes = content.selectAll("#nodes")
     .data(nodesData),
    nodesEnter = nodes.enter().append("g")
     .attr("id", "nodes"),
    node = nodes.selectAll(".node")
     .data(id),
    newNode = node.enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "node")
     .call(force.drag),
    circles = newNode.append("circle")
     .attr({class: "content"})
     .attr("r", function(d) {return d.r})
     .style({"fill": "red", opacity: 0.8});

  lines.exit().remove();
  node.exit().remove();

  function nodesData(d) {
   return [d.nodes];
  }

  function linksData(d) {
   return d.edges;
  }

  function hookDrag(target, event, hook) {
   //hook force.drag behaviour
   var stdDragStart = target.on(event);
   target.on(event, function(d) {
    hook.call(this, d);
    stdDragStart.call(this, d);
   });
  }

  function zoomed(){
   var e = d3.event.sourceEvent,
     isWheel = e && ((e.type == "mousewheel") || (e.type == "wheel"));
   force.alpha(0.01);
   return isWheel ? zoomWheel.call(this) : zoomInst.call(this)
  }
  function zoomInst(){
   var t = d3.transform(content.attr("transform"));
   t.translate = d3.event.translate; t.scale = d3.event.scale;
   content.attr("transform", t.toString());
  }
  function zoomWheel(){
   var t = d3.transform(content.attr("transform"));
   t.translate = d3.event.translate; t.scale = d3.event.scale;
   content.transition().duration(450).attr("transform", t.toString());
  }

  fdg.force = force;

 };
 return fdg

}
function id(d){return d;}
```

```css
svg {
      outline: 1px solid #282f51;
      pointer-events: all;
      overflow: visible;
    }

    g.outline {
      outline: 1px solid red;
    }

    #panel div {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 .25em 3px 0; 
      
    }
    #panel div div {
      white-space: pre;
    }
    div#inputDiv {
      white-space: normal;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .node {
      cursor: default;
    }

    text {
      font-size: 8px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/cool-Blue/40e550b1507cca31b0bb/raw/b83ceb0f8b4a2b6256f079f5887fc5243baedd4f/elapsed%2520time%25201.0.js"></script>
<div id="panel">
  <div id="inputDiv">
    <input id="update" type="button" value="update">
  </div>
  <div id="wrapAlpha">alpha:
    <div id="alpha"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="fdg">
</div>
<div id="viz"></div>
```

Comment: Your example is great. That's what I want. But until now I was not able to apply it on my code. I gonna try to achieve it today. Thank you.

Comment: OK, sorry, it had some extra features left over from another question, but now it is simplified and focused for your question.  Make sure you use today's version ;)

Comment: Finally found some time for testing. Works great indeed. Thank you very much. Also now online on the website. =) And also working on the map now when using **smooth**. Thank you so much dude.

Comment: @kwoxer OK, good!  It was an interesting study for me so thanks for sharing.  Just for interest, run [_**these two files**_](https://gist.github.com/cool-Blue/42514ca0daad76ecfde9/0fc2ec8e15418cb705a99eaedc5a29071b9032a7) against your site.  I added a feature that gives you an instant refresh when you do show all after hide all (you don't have to wait for the Ajax).  Also, there are a few things that you do that are not quite idiomatic in d3, and these files show you how to use it the way it was intended to be used.

Comment: I also show you how to allow the `force.drag` mouseover behaviour to coexist with yours by hooking the `drag.on("mouseover")`, so you get the `force.drag` node capture plus your transition on the names.

Comment: Thank you. I was so busy today so that I didn't find time. But it looks pretty good. Will definitily implement that. But I'm now 1 week without internet. Will come back with more information in over a week. Please let your files online if possible. And really big thanks again dude =) Till then.

Comment: Mhh I just copied you code now, but it is not in any way what I would like to have^^. Could you maybe explain what your intention was, or which lines you changed and why? I mean I want to learn and improve my code even more, but your complete js-file is totally behaving wrong. Your first idea was great, just to mention that. I works now as I wanted to have it. But as I said, you can always improve more. So please tell me some more about your code. Thank you =)

Comment: @kwoxer, OK, can you clarify what you did to try it? Before I posted them I ran [these two files](https://gist.github.com/cool-Blue/42514ca0daad76ecfde9/0fc2ec8e15418cb705a99eaedc5a29071b9032a7) as replacements for the files of the same name in your site and they ran perfectly. Is that what you did?  They are direct replacements... If that's what you did then is there any way you can provide a link to the revised site with the changes made?

Comment: @kwoxer, I just tried them again against your site as it is now and they run fine.  The changes I made were to eliminate things like `svg.remove();`.  If you do it right, d3 allows you to drive everything about the dom _just by changing the data_ and then just update the viz (and update is also initialise).  This makes it a lot easier to implement instant hide all - show all, without having to re-load.  this also avoids chaotic behaviour on show all.  I also showed how to _hook_ the default force drag, and keep the default behaviour, but still have your custom mouse events as well.

Comment: @kwoxer how did you go man? Any luck getting it to work? I ran it using Fiddler as a proxy to redirect to my version of the files, that's how I tested it. We can chat about it in GitHub if you like...

Comment: I would love to chat with you. Because I tried it again and it still has the mistakes. =/

Comment: @kwoxer, OK, lets chat [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85174/31469803)

Comment: you should have... I set it up before... at least I think I did... it's freakin confusing...

Comment: I answered you in the chat. I don't if you got an information about that. Thank you.

Comment: @kwoxer, I also replied in the chat room with a fix for your problem...  Can chat now if you like.

Comment: @kwoxer, if you are interested I used your page to practice MVC architecture and the result is in [this git repo](https://github.com/cool-Blue/SO-Questions/tree/fetch-once-mvc) It turned out quite good, after I simplified by moving to MVC it was a lot easier to figure out how to speed things up. Now the instant unhide is back and requested singles are cached so instant after the first time. The code is a bit simpler and easier to follow because I moved all of the data management into an object in orientdb and passed all coms between objects via familytree.js.  It was a very nice study case.

Comment: Jap, looks like a really good cleanup my friend. Thank you. I have now uploaded all the new stuff. So if you really want to go any further, then until now already, please take the latest files.  =)

Comment: Yeh, I'm still interested, check out a new feature I added for searching in [the repo](https://github.com/cool-Blue/SO-Questions/tree/fetch-once-mvc) I think it's better if we comunicate there.

Comment: @kwoxer let me know if you want to collaborate further on this. Leave a message in the repo if you do.

Comment: Hey cool you really keeped on working on it man =) I just checked the diff to my current version. It seems that you did not use my latest version somehow =/. But as always I like the changes so I wanted to test it out. But anyways I your code is getting several issues on the method names. Did it work for you? Sad but I'm sure that we can get it running? I think comments are better here then on Github =) Thank you.

Comment: @kwoxer, oh ok, I didn't realise there were other changes in the version you have up. No problem, I will check it out and merge to my lates version. Meanwhile, let's chat in GitHub, [please open a new issue there](https://github.com/cool-Blue/SO-Questions/issues). It works fine for me by the way.

Comment: I have an idea. These days I wanted to upload all the stuff of this project somehow or other =) So let me upload all the stuff without your changes here and could you afterwards bring your changes in there. I know that's not that cool for you to work again on the same things. But then the project is complete and you don't need a subproject on your side. But gimme some time =)

Comment: Alright it's online: https://github.com/kwoxer/Arda-Maps/commits/master Your Version and the latest of mine, the working one. Maybe you see my mistake that did not manage to run your version. Thank you =) And now let's chat there, as it's the official Github space of Arda Maps now. =)

Comment: Ok, excellent! I don't mind a bit figuring out how to merge the different versions, part of my reason for doing this was to learn about GitHub so it's all good.